# How to filter the name in the select options angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element, which has a name and id as a option value. and am adding '-' along with name. There is a scenario where the name will be empty, the '-' should not be shown.

the expected should be some thing like this.

> 1. name - 123
> 2. 123

this is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
    <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.Title as item.Title + '-' + item.ID for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.model = {
    selected : 'Chicago'
  }
    $scope.items = [
       {ID: '000.000.0001', Title: 'Chicago'},
       {ID: '000.000.0002', Title: 'New York'},
       {ID: '000.000.0003', Title: 'Washington'}
    ];  
});
```

Comment: so your question is how to hide the '-' on default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the if-else expression like this:  `OK? yes:no`.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.model = {
      selected: 'Chicago'
    }
    $scope.items = [{
        ID: '000.000.0001',
        Title: 'Chicago'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0002',
        Title: 'New York'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0003',
        Title: 'Washington'
      },
      {
        ID: '000.000.0004'
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.Title as item.Title? (item.Title + '-' + item.ID) : ('' + item.ID) for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Correct your controller and APP name in app.js file.
Then update you code as follows.

```
<select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.Title as (item.Title !==''? item.Title + '-' : '') + item.ID for item in items"></select>
```